# How would I call the following methods in another class? java

Tags: java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class calling {


public static int num1() {
int x;
Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter a number called x: ");
x=scanner.nextInt();
return x;    
}

public static int num2() {
int y;
Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter a second number called y: ");
y=scanner.nextInt();
return y;    
}

public static String operand() {
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
String s;
System.out.println("What process would you like to do? *, /, + or - ?");
s=input.next();
return s;
}

public static void calculation(int x, int y, String s) {
String t;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


if (s.equals("*")) {
System.out.println("\nThe product of these numbers is:" + (x*y));}
else 
if (s.equals("+")) {
System.out.println("\nThe sum of these numbers is: " + (x+y));}

System.out.println("\nDo you want x or y to be the dividor/subtractor?: ");
t=input.next();

if (t.equals("y") || t.equals("Y") ) {

if (s.equals("/")) {
System.out.println("\nThe quotient of these numbers is:  " + (x/y));}
else 
if (s.equals("-")) {
System.out.println("\nThe difference of these numbers is: " + (x-y));}}

else 
if (t.equals("x") || t.equals("X")){

if (s.equals("/")) {
System.out.println("\nThe quotient of these numbers is: " + (y/x));}
else 
if (s.equals("-")) {
System.out.println("\nThe difference of these numbers is: " + ((y-x)));}}
}

public static void  main (String [] args) throws IOException {


int x1=num1();
int y1=num2();
String s1=operand();
calculation(x1, y1, s1);




}

}
```

How would I call these methods into a new class so i can run the program from it? I understand typically you would put the name of the class.nameofmethod(); but how would i pass the parameters and such?
I am a beginner in Java so all help would be greatly appreciated!
thanks in advance guys.

Comment: You'd pass the parameters by... passing the parameters, like `StaticCalculatorClass.calculation(5, 10, "wat")`. But this method is almost certainly incorrect; you pass in a string then immediate overwrite it with input from a scanner. You'd also want the methods to be non-static, so they're instance methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all the methods are static you can just do:

```
int x1=calling.num1();
int y1=calling.num2();
String s1=calling.operand();
calling.calculation(x1, y1, s1);
```

But, if you didn't make them static and you wanted to call them then you instantiate a class and call the methods in that class.

```
calling app = new calling();
int x1=app.num1();
int y1=app.num2();
String s1=app.operand();
app.calculation(x1, y1, s1);
```

Comment: the calling.calculation(x1, y1, s1); gives me an error on the brackets :S

Answer (score 3):

As an example:

```
int x = calling.num1();
System.out.println(x);
```

...stores the result of the `num1()` method in x then prints out the contents of x.

In terms of parameters:

```
calling.calculation(4,5,"+");
```

The fact you need to ask this suggests that you should probably go away and read up and follow through on some very basic Java tutorials such as the one here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/index.html - That's not an attack at all, just a suggestion of how to best broaden your knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

There are no parameters to pass as all of your methods are parameterless.  What you would do would be to accept the int returned from the method:

```
int myResult = Myclass.MyMethod();
```

edit: except for your calculation method that is, but you appear to know how to use this. Now I'm not sure exactly what your problem is since you are using the methods OK in the main method (except you're not calling them off of the class name, but don't have to if the main method is inside of the class itself).

Comment: calculation() takes parameters ;)

Comment: @berry120: yep, I noticed that and edited my answer. 1+ to your nice answer by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You have a bigger problems than this.
Please start reading the book Clean Code by Robert C. Martin, your code is not object oriented